# How to replace an audio tag with a video tag in Javascript or replacing a tag with another tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I want to replace all `<audio>` tags with `<video>` tags in an html document. How do I do that with a javascript function?

Please help me with writing the function. I have no clue about it and thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it easily in jquery do you have this option !? if not why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, should work.

```
var aud = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
while(aud[0]){
    var v = document.createElement("video");
    var a = aud[0].attributes;
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) v.setAttribute(a[i].nodeName,a[i].nodeValue);
    v.innerHTML = aud[0].innerHTML;
    aud[0].parentNode.insertBefore(v,aud[0]);
    aud[0].parentNode.removeChild(aud[0]);
}​
```

That should keep everything inside, but just replace the tag.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8m59n/ - you'll have to inspect it with firebug or web inspector to see.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
function functionname(){
  document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace('audio>','video>');
}
```